# Is it possible to view an entire M365 tenant's Exchange data in PowerBI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, microsoft365, microsoft-exchange

Apologies in advanced, I'm not a PowerBI user. I would like to know if this customer's query is possible with PowerBI before I send them elsewhere:

The customer would like to see a weekly report highlighting the total number of emails received from external contacts and the total number of emails received from internal contacts. The same but for sent emails. They would also like a breakdown of how many external emails are responded to, and the time taken between responses - averages would be best if possible.

If you think this is something PowerBI can pull from Exchange please let me know so I can outsource to a third party. If not perhaps another tool would do the trick?

Thanks!

I have tried connecting to the Exchange online module in PowerBI, but only got the option to connect to one email at a time. I would need to see the entire tenant's emails.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI is just the reporting end point in a process like this. It can certainly handle the reporting of the data but it can't retrieve the data. The real work would be writing a powershell script to extract relevant data using MS Graph and then storing that in a DB in Azure for PowerBI to then connect to.

Comment: Thank you. Glad it's possible. Ill take a look at MS Graph